How to union arrays of items?
I have a json structure in Java with repeating lists of similar objects under different categories that I want to query with JSonPath:
{"root":
{"cars":[
{"make":"Ford", "colour":"white", "doors":4},
{"make":"Audi", "colour":"silver","doors":2}
],
"vans":[
{"make":"Ford", "colour":"blue", "weight":2}
]
}}

I want to return the colour of the third vehicle, so was hoping to do:
$.root.[cars,vans][2].colour

But it seems the [cars,vans] expression returns an array-of-arrays and not a single unioned/concatenated array of all the vehicles, and the index operator [2] is applied to each of the cars and vans arrays separately (returning nothing), rather than the union of them (which should return the van).
$.root.[cars,vans][0].colour 

returns the first car and the first van, while
$.root.[cars,vans][0].colour[0] 

returns the first letter of each of the colours of the first car and first van,
$.root.[cars,vans][1].colour 

returns just the second car.
Similarly, using wildcard returns the same array-of-arrays:
$.root.*[0].colour

Is there a way to union the result of the [cars,vans] union, e.g. by using:
$.root.[[cars,vans]][2].colour

Or will I need to code my own adaptation of one of the Java implementations?

I don't think that JSONPath expressions supports what you're trying to achieve. I could only go as far  as  flattening both arrays $.root.[cars,vans][*]. Selecting the last item can  be done programatically.

If you were will to swap to using something like jsonata, i think that would be able to do this

Thanks both. I'll look at jsonata, and if not will roll my own parser/extension for JSONPath.

In JSONPath you can't have the result you expected, the best JSONPath can do is $..colour that return an array like this ["white","silver","blue"] then you can compute the third element of the array futher in you program.
Or you can use JMESPATH to solve this problem with this query : @.root.[*][][].colour | [2] and it return exactly blue.
Or you can use jq to solve this with this query : .root | flatten | .[2].colour  and it return exactly blue.
